# java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl cannot be cast to sun.util.logging.LoggingProxy

Tags: java, jboss

I am using JBoss-7.1.0 with JDK-7.  I am getting the following stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.logging.LoggingProxyImpl cannot be cast to sun.util.logging.LoggingProxy
```

Can any one know solution to this exception?

Answer (score 0):

https://access.redhat.com/site/discussions/792203

The solution was to add 'path name="sun/util/logging"/' to jboss\modules\system\layers\base\sun\jdk\main\module.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I have tried this already but it did not worked for me :(

Comment: i'm sorry...:( are you restarted server?

Comment: maybe try to use this logger at you application sun.util.logging.LoggingProxy or if you are using maven specify the dependency of logger compile.  be lucky.